# Joomla New Article in 404 Status

Tags: joomla-3.x

All of our articles are published but when I publish a new one it would have 404 status.

**Error**

`exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Error decoding JSON data: unexpected end of data' in /var/www/html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Format/Json.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php(366): Joomla\Registry\Format\Json->stringToObject('{"menu_image":"...', Array) #1 /var/www/html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php(72): Joomla\Registry\Registry->loadString('{"menu_image":"...') #2 /var/www/html/components/com_content/models/article.php(162): Joomla\Registry\Registry->__construct('{"menu_image":"...') #3 /var/www/html/libraries/legacy/view/legacy.php(422): ContentModelArticle->getItem() #4 /var/www/html/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php(42): JViewLegacy->get('Item') #5 /var/www/html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(671): ContentViewArticle->display() #6 /var/www/html/components/com_content/controller.php(113):` `JControllerLegacy->display(false, Array) #7 /var/www/html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(709): ContentController->display() #8 /var/www/html/components/com_content/content.php(39): JControllerLegacy->execute(NULL) #9 /var/www/html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(394): require_once('/var/www/html/c...') #10 /var/www/html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(369): JComponentHelper::executeComponent('/var/www/html/c...') #11 /var/www/html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_content') #12 /var/www/html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch() #13 /var/www/html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(265): JApplicationSite->doExecute() #14 /var/www/html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute() #15 {main}`

Comment: We need more information than that. What version are you running? When did the problem start? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please reinstall the last Joomla Update / Core files.